# Traverse Generic STL Container To Check For Existence

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, stl

I'm trying to write a template function to return true if a given object already exists in a container. This is where I'm at, and I don't know where to go from here.

```
 template <typename BeginningIter, typename EndingIter, typename T>
 static bool itemExists(BeginningIter bit, EndingIter eit, const T &searchTerm)
 {
     if ((bit == nullptr) || (eit == nullptr)) {
         return false;
     }  
     static_assert(std::is_same<std::decay(decltype(*bit)), std::decay(searchTerm)>::value, "Invalid");
     for (auto iter = bit; iter != eit; iter++) {
         if (*iter == searchTerm) {
             return true;
         }
     }
     return false;
}
```

I also though to try to use std::enable_if in the template specification line, but I didn't know of a way to get the type of a dereferenced BeginningIter term. I used the std::decay in case it was pointing to a reference type. However, when trying to compile, I get

```
generalutilities.h: In static member function ‘static bool GeneralUtilities::itemExists(BeginningIter, EndingIter, const T&)’:
generalutilities.h:148:77: error: template argument 1 is invalid
         if (!std::is_same<std::decay(decltype(*bit)), std::decay(searchTerm)>::value) {
                                                                             ^
generalutilities.h:148:77: error: template argument 2 is invalid
```

Comment: "*I'm trying to write a template function to return true if a given object already exists in a container.*" FYI: we already have one of those. [It's called `find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find). And it's much better than yours, since it returns the location where it was found, and it doesn't require the type of an element in the container to be the exact type as what you're searching for.

Comment: Yeah, I know about find. I'm jist trying to learn tenplates.

Comment: `if(!std::is_same<...>::value) { std::cout << "Not the same" << std::endl; }` That should probably be a `static_assert`

Comment: @KABoissonneault thanks, I'll change it when I get home

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
>  std::decay(decltype(*bit))
> ```

[`std::decay`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay) is not a function; it is a metafunction. IE: a struct with a `::type` member (or `::value` for metafunction's that result in values). And you can't call regular functions by passing a type anyway.

You call a metafunction it by using `typename std::decay<decltype(*bit)>::type`. The `typename` part is rather important.

Pre-C++14, you would make your code shorter by creating a quick alias template:

```
template<typename T> using decay_t = typename std::decay<T>::type;
```

C++14 makes that part of the standard library for all type metafunctions.